# Creating Installable ISO for mSATA harddisk

Tags: iso, buildroot

Am trying to build small OS using buildroot & able to generate iso hybrid image to boot from USB. Generated iso image is working fine as live CD but not able to install it inside hard disk (like regular OS image).

I have tried to modify /init but need more guidance for doing so. Any help here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To install on a hard disk, you want a regular root filesystem + kernel. Select:

- `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INSTALL_TARGET` "Install kernel image to /boot in target" to make the kernel part of the rootfs.
- `grub2` as the bootloader;
- `ext4` as the root filesystem;
- `host-genimage` to create a partitioned hard disk image

You also need to supply:

- a `grub.cfg` to configure grub;
- a post-build script to copy the `grub.cfg` to the right place;
- a `genimage.cfg` to configure the hard disk image.

Look at `configs/pc_x86_64_efi_defconfig` for inspiration. You might even be able to use it directly.